# Mapa de calor con leaflet y heatmap no funciona el control de capas L.control.layers

Tags: mysqli, leaflet

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Estoy creando un mapa de calor con leaflet y heatmap mi problema es que no funciona el control de capas(L.control.layers) para Mapa de  Calor(Heatmap) que necesito configurar o donde esta mi error ya que solo falla en activar o desactivar el mapa de calor lo deja FIJO

```
var puntos= L.geoJson(null, {
  onEachFeature: popup,
  pointToLayer: charcos,
});
 $.getJSON("puntos.php", function (data) {
      var locations = data.features.map(function(rat) {
      var location = rat.geometry.coordinates.reverse();
      location.push(5);
      return location; 
    });
    var puntos = L.heatLayer(locations, { radius: 11 });
    puntos.addTo(map);
});
puntos.addTo(map);

//Inicia control de Capas
var baseMaps = {
    "Google": cartodbLayer,
    "Carto": CartoDB_DarkMatter
};

var overlayMaps = {
    "Perimetro CDMX": limite,
  "Fugas": charcos
};

L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps,{
    position: 'topright', 
    collapsed: false 
}).addTo(map);
```

Este es mi codigo que funciona, la primera capa .geojson sin problema la puedo desactivar y activar el problema surge en la capa de $.getJSON("charcos.php", function (data)) ya que no me deja desactivarla la deja fija desde un principio y esta capa es la que muestra el mapa de calor con todos los puntos no es problema de mi consulta PHP ya que los datos los muestra sin problema.
Solo que al utilizarlos para mapa de calor es donde deja Fijo el mapa de calor y no se puede desactivar o activar.
Este problema surgió porque quiero poner dos mapas de calor de diferentes puntos estos que muestro son del año 2019 y quiero otra capa con diferentes puntos del año 2018
Las dos capas en mapas de Calor.

```
var limite = L.geoJson(null, {
    style : limite,
    onEachFeature: popup
});
$.getJSON("PCDMXline.geojson", function (data3) {
    limite.addData(data3);
});
limite.addTo(map);
//Esta es la capa de los puntos para el mapa de calor que no funciona
//Se queda fija y no me permite deactivarla o activarla
var charcos = L.geoJson(null, {
  onEachFeature: popup,
  pointToLayer: charcos,
});
$.getJSON("charcos.php", function (data) {
      var locations = data.features.map(function(rat) {
      var location = rat.geometry.coordinates.reverse();
      location.push(5);
      return location; 
    });
    var charcos = L.heatLayer(locations, { radius: 11 });
    charcos.addTo(map);
});
charcos.addTo(map);

//Inicia control de Capas
var baseMaps = {
    "Google": cartodbLayer,
    "Carto": CartoDB_DarkMatter
};

var overlayMaps = {
    "Perimetro CDMX": limite,
  "Fugas": charcos
};
L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps,{
    position: 'topright', 
    collapsed: false 
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: y el error que ves en consola ?

Comment: hola gracias por tu comentario, no me marca ningún error en consola. solo al momento de querer desactivar o activar la capa no me deja, ya que el mapa de calor lo deja Fijo